# Does hyphenation increase readability?

Tags: typography, hyphenation, research

All I could find on the subject was [this paper](https://ritdml.rit.edu/handle/1850/13571), which is pretty interesting in itself. But it only deals with *preference*. 57% of the test subject prefers hyphenated text.

This is kind of surprising to me, because I get the feeling hyphenation hinders the ability to take up the entire word in one glance. Does anyone know whether there are any experiments out there that measure actual reading time?

---

Glassman, Tracy (1997). *Principles of Typography for the Screen*. Master’s thesis. Rochester NY, USA: Rochester Institute of Technology.

Comment: To nitpick...in the context of graphic design, you are asking about hyphenation and *readability*--not legibility: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legibility But yes, most readability studies end up measuring preferences, not necessarily scientifically provable differences.

Comment: Quite right. Changed the title.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Why justify

Justification can make an important contribution to extended reading: **Taming the visual 'noise' in a page of text.** Nick Shinn made a [particularly keen observation](http://typophile.com/node/16395#comment-98685) in this regard on Typophile:

> Justification avoids the "interference" of having shapes and
>   coinicidences occur at the right column edge, which can be a
>   distraction, as the reader will interpret these as potentially
>   significant. And indeed they may be, as statistically a short line
>   tends to indicate a paragraph end.

You'll see that most long text documents use justified setting. Justified setting can fall apart without hyphenation, ending up with gaping holes in the text. The holes create a situation where a reader accidentally jumps between lines, losing their place in the text. So, consequently, hyphenation increases legibility in this case by eliminating a bigger problem.

There has been research specifically on readers' ability to 'see' words when hyphenated and there was no loss of comprehension -- of course, I can't dig up any of that info now :/ I suspect longer texts benefit from more able readers and greater context so any gaps that do arise are filled in cognitively.

### How to justify

The trouble is, setting justified text is a skill that takes time to master. Here's a [**Typophile thread on fine tuning your justification settings**](http://typophile.com/node/3989). This is a fantastic, detailed overview from some real masters of text setting. Unfortunately, Kent Lew's valuable settings window screen shot is now missing. There's still plenty to learn there.

That discussion highlights a very important consideration: **Employ the full gamut of justification control provided in long-document layout software for the best results.** You can achieve better justified spacing and fewer hyphens if you set proper limits on

- Word spacing
- Character spacing
- Character scaling (just a little please)

[image: This all depends on context, of course.]

### Just for fun

And how could you complete a typography debate without a little client bashing: [This lengthy discussion on Typophile](http://typophile.com/node/30235) centers around a client that wanted hyphenation eliminated. There is some great stuff in there, including links to related discussions. Synopsis:

- Justified text without hyphenation is a bad idea.
- Justified or Flush Left is a matter of taste.
- A narrow measure without hyphenation will fail.

(Can you sense my obsession with the topic?)

Comment: One of my professors once told me, as a rule of thumb, hyphenate **at most** twice per paragraph. I sadly didn't have the forethought to ask him what his source was.

Comment: You have to use your intuition. In long-document software you have the option to set a limit on consecutive hyphens (line-to-line). Two is my usual number simply for presentation reasons -- more than that seems like a visual distraction to me. In newspaper setting, this isn't always possible because the lines are so short.

Comment: I think it is all a matter of taste, it is just that justified text has two competing bad choices: hyphenate or word spacing. Most people seem to agree that word spacing tastes worse. Personally, I have huge problems with hyphenation because I tend to read them as phrasal adjectives, and I wind up with the so-called "garden-path problem."

Comment: The important thing to remember when researching or empirically analyzing or setting justified texts: **It's really easy to set really bad justified text.** With flush left you don't have to balance the needs of the typeface, point size, measure, and leading to the same critical degree. Study with someone (or read from someone) who knows what they're doing before you justify!

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that there's tunable but automatic hyphenation, and then there's individually and intelligently placing every (discretionary) hyphen yourself.

Comment: God be with you if you try that on a 1000 page book! I have done extensive work in the hyphenation dictionary in InDesign (and QXP many moons ago) but hand-placed discretionary hyphens are not a thing for extended texts.

Comment: Yes,  I did mean to say that there is a quality-practicality tradeoff!

Comment: Justification is just a tool. This tool lets you put **maximum** amount of words in a particular page. Where it can be used properly? In newspapers, dictionaries, cheap books. But on the web (where space cost nothing) I prefer blank line between paragraphs, just like on this site or wikipedia.

Comment: @yakunins hyphenation is not about maxing out the average word count of your page. It has to do with word spacing, the visual perception of word groups, and taming the chaos of a page to assist [saccadic eye movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccade). And what does a blank line have to do with hyphenation?

Comment: @plainclothes The question was about hyphenation, not about justification. Did you read your answer? Please, remove the parts about justification (Why justify, How to justify) from the answer.

Comment: @yakunins Welcome to the wonderful world of typesetting! For your first lesson we'll talk about the close historical ties between hyphenation and justification.

Comment: With certain combinations of text contents, font, and margin settings, there will be no choice but to either accept horrible-looking results or hyphen-break a word. If those parameters can be tweaked, however--especially if the text can be reworded--hyphenation may be far less necessary.  Someone doing layout shouldn't rework text without consulting the author, but in some cases it may be worthwhile to work with the author to formulate a text that will lay out nicely.

Answer (score 16):

All given answers here seems to be only for English.

I just want to add another language: *German*.

German has a lot of long words (much longer as English words). If you want to typeset a German text on paper with justification you *can do it only* with hyphenations. LaTeX does a very good job with *automatic* hyphenations for the German language. It also knows the rule that in German there are only a maximum of 3 consecutive hyphens (ladders, rows above each other with hyphenations at the end of the line) allowed.

Hyphenation is only bad if it can change the meaning of the hyphenated word, for example the German verb "beinhalten" should **only** hyphenated as "be-inhalten" (contain, containing) and **not** as "bein-halten" (could be read as "Bein halten" (leg hold)).

Comment: That's a good point, Kurt. The OP didn't mention a specific language consideration. I did make a passing mention of the challenges of German type setting [in another post](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13455/4216), but we haven't had a question specifically addressing it.

Comment: Interesting. Kurt: when you say "in German there are only a maximum of 3 rows above each other with hyphenations are allowed", are you talking about [ladders / consecutive hyphens, like in this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12925/hyphenation-on-many-line-breaks)?

Comment: @user568458: Yes, I didn't know that it is named "ladders" in English. In a German book with good typography you will never find more than 3 consecutive hyphens.

Answer (score 7):

Here's [an article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line) from the *English Language & Usage Stack Exchange* with some varying opinions.

Personal opinion: don't hyphenate flush left text. Hyphenation is only acceptable in long documents and even then it should be regulated.

Comment: Personal opinion, because I have nothing to back it with other than 20 years of typesetting experience: I would ALWAYS choose hyphenated text over crazy rags or huge rivers in justified text. Hyphens are essentially invisible, and if you set the program correctly (that is, no two-letter breaks) and proof your work (to avoid *the-rapist* for *therapist*), 95% of the time hyphens make text easier to read.

Comment: Vigilance is the key though: if they are as invisible as you think, they are harder to proof. I think "the-rapist" is second only to "pubic funding" in unfortunate tpyos and errs.

Comment: @Ian: Are you talking about justified or flush left text or both?

Comment: @e100 I was talking about flush left.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum You make a good point. It's a decision of stylistic preference to not hyphenate. When I do so, it's short form text and I track the type to control rag and rivers.

Comment: @horatio, that's funny, but note that therapist would be hyphenated after the 'ther'. :) (But it's still a very valid point!)